# iPhone - iTunesConnect automation

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app that has about 50 in-app purchases in 4 languages, what give me a lot of forms and subforms, boxes and sub boxes to fill using the excruciating and badly designed forms of iTunesConnect.

I am wondering if there's a way to automate that. I thought about using automator, but I am not sure if it will have the precision to do that. I have thought about applescript, but I don't know if it can be that precise to fill the right fields with the right information read from a file.

Is there a way to do that? what's the best approach?

thanks

btw: it would be possible to develop an application that could wrap a layer of automatism to that stuff?

Comment: I came across something the other day - need to find it again.. It was based on automator, looked like a browser. Not selenium or tagsoup - something more towards click recording..

Comment: on the WWDC Apple demoed (and announced for this fall) a new Mac app to bulk upload data for In App Purchase. Be patient and do your uploads manually now!

Comment: really? That would be amazing, but they should extend the software to bypass iTunesConnect completely. iTC site stinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has provided a tool for this kinf of job, it's called "Application Loader". You can get it from iTunes Connect (subsection "Manage Your Applications").

When you launch Application Manager (and enter your iTunes credentials), choose:
1) Create New Package
2) New from file
3) Choose an CSV spreadsheet with all the metadata about your IAPs.

The spreadsheet should contain all the fields about the IAP as columns and different IAPs as rows. It should be quite self-explanatory from there on. Notice that you still have to provide separate screenshot files for each IAP.

Comment: I know about this tool. This tool is good because you can upload new stuff in batches, but is limited because you cannot edit or change in batches stuff that is already there. I have around 1,000 in-apps spread around 10 apps. It is a pain in the neck to edit stuff when needed. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @RubberDuck You have been asking if there is a possibility to upload an app you are programming at the moment so this looks to me as the most appropriate answer. It can also prevent you from mistaktes when creating the app the first time.

Comment: at the time I accepted the other answer, this one was not good, because Application Loader was doing a crappy job of automation, not creating packages for hosted contents, for example. After iOS 7, they fixed that.

Comment: This is not really a good app because there seems to be no way of refreshing the info after its created. Also at the moment I have no way to set the price tier even adding an IAP manually in the app.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at fast lane:

http://fastlane.tools/

It's designed to do that.

Comment: I searched all over that site but nowhere does it mention IAP.

Answer (score 2):

Ah. I found it, but have not tried it - and it was not free :/
http://fakeapp.com/

Otherwise, it should be possible to use curl where you can set login and cookies.

Comment: How much is your time worth to you?

Comment: Would you rather spend $30 on a tool or X days/weeks making your own. It was a rhetorical question. Good tools/resources are worth paying for.

Comment: Seemed like decent app(s) and reasonably priced. Or I would have left it out of the equation :)
Opensource is preffered though.

I think the best reason to do tedious tasks with apps is that you might avoid some errors. (sure, might create some too).

Looking forward to see the new bulk tools.